# Can I have consecutive inheritance with Themes?

Tags: json, themes, shopware6

I use multiple saleschannel for shops with different languages but till now it was not necessary to have different views or styling.

Unfortunately this is not the case anymore and I tried to create two themes inheriting from the one I currently use. This Theme is already inheriting from another theme though.

The theme.json of the latest theme looks like that:

```
{
    "name": "NewTheme",
    "author": "Me",
    "configInheritance": [
        "@Storefront",
        "@OldestTheme"
    ],
    "views": [
        "@Storefront",
        "@Plugins",
        "@OldestTheme",
        "@NewTheme"
    ],
    "style": [
        "app/storefront/src/scss/overrides.scss",
        "@Storefront",
        "@OldestTheme",
        "app/storefront/src/scss/base.scss"
    ],
    "script": [
        "@Storefront",
        "@OldestTheme",
        "app/storefront/dist/storefront/js/new-theme.js"
    ],
    "asset": [
        "@Storefront",
        "@OldestTheme",
        "app/storefront/src/assets",
        "public"
    ]
}
```

What I want to achieve is my latest theme to inherit from my current Theme which inherits from my oldest theme. I did not manage to do that and would like to know if this is possible within Shopware 6.

The documentation about theme inheritance does not have the information I seek (https://developer.shopware.com/docs/v6.4/guides/plugins/themes/add-theme-inheritance.html).

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working similar as described in your question. The inheritance order also seems to be correct. Make sure to run the following commands:

1. `bin/console theme:refresh`
2. `bin/console theme:compile`
3. `bin/console cache:clear`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will have a look!

Comment: Seems like the refresh did wonders. Thank you very much.